# pop is not appearing if the values are having an line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which is showing the details, and the details come from the backend. If the details have an Line break character, the pop up is not working. 
Here is the function called on click of that button:

```
function showCommentInfo(comment,elem){
        jQuery("#order-info dl").remove();
        jQuery('#close-order-info-wrapper').after("<dl><dt>"+comment+"</dt></dl>");

}
```

Comment: Where are `comment` and `elem` coming from? How are you calling this function?

Comment: Replace newline character `\r|\n` with `<br/>` using regex at server side coding.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Bad idea. If newlines are causing the code to break, it's a sign of a bigger problem that you'll just make worse.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol there is problem with newline so I suggest to replace the comment with the character supports in html. so whats wrong here?

Comment: @RajeshKumar That would be a good idea, *if* the problem was "newlines are not showing up", but that's not the case. This question is "newlines **break the code**" and that suggests that the comment text is being injected directly into the code. If this is the case, the site is vulnerable to massive security issues, and just naively replacing newlines with HTML tags will probably just make things worse, not better, since it allows HTML to be injected...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am agree with your point but if the problem is only with rendering text then It could help

Comment: @RajeshKumar Right, but that's *not* the problem and your comment does more harm than good if followed...

Comment: Let's wait and see what is the actual problem...

Comment: We are entring the text from a comment box and it should come in popup. when the text is having any line which start from next line or having "enter"  between them the popup is not appearning. for that what i have done is this String comment = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "flagComment").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", ""); ignoring the line break but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys this solved my problem

```
String comment = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "flagComment").replace("\n","</br>");
```